# Reduce MySQL query execution time

Tags: php, mysql

I am using two different databases `tbl_data1` (has 10000 rows) and `tbl_data2` (has 2.5 million rows). Updating using the source code below takes too long. Is there any way to reduce the time taken to update the values in first database?

```
 $query="select * from tbl_data1";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {   
        $account=$row["A_Account"];
        $query1="select * from tbl_data2 where D_Account='$account'";   
        $result1=mysqli_query($con1,$query1);
        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            $product=$row1["D_Account_Type"];
            $query3="update tbl_data set A_Product='$product' where A_Account='$account'";
            $result3=mysqli_query($con,$query3);
            if (!$result3) 
            {
                die('Invalid query2: ' . mysqli_error());
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Use **JOIN**s...

Comment: select * from is a bad habbit, try to put feild names insted of *

Answer (score 2):

You can write a single update query with `JOIN`, e.g.:

```
UPDATE tbl_data td
JOIN tbl_data2 td2 ON td.A_Account = td2.D_Account_Type
JOIN tbl_data1 ON td2.D_Account = td1.A_Account
SET td.A_Product = '$product';
```

This means you won't need to iterate both the tables (td1 and td2) and execution will be faster.

**update**

If you want to set the value of `td.A_Product` to the value of either `td1` or `td2`'s column then you can just do:

```
SET td.A_Product = td1.product
```

OR

```
SET td.A_Product = td2.product
```

Comment: both the tables are on different database.

Comment: As per my understanding in this query, you set the value static "product" but it is based on the previous table.

Comment: well, in that case, it can just be `td1.prouct` or `td2.product` (I actually meant `$product`, updated the answer). However, it's not clear which table it belongs to. I will anyway update the answer again.

Comment: Sure @DarshanMehta even it's look like OP has not mention properly which table belong to which database. seeing this post looks like all belong to single database

Comment: @Santosh true, I have updated the answer anyway. Will edit it more if OP has any follow up questions.

Comment: @DarshanMehta Sure. ;)